# Rails 3 / HAML: How can I output haml raw from a variable?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, layout, haml

I have some variables within rails that contain some divs like so:

```
@layout_1 = "
.box_1 
.column_4 <br>
.gutter<br>
.column_4<br>
.gutter<br>
.column_4<br>
.gutter<br>
.column_4<br>"
```

This is coming from a database, and the idea is to swap layouts on request, but how can I output the variable (`@layout_1`) as HAML inside a HAML file ?

If I were to use normal html divs, I would use `<%=raw` or `.html_safe`

Answer (score 11):

you would do the same with HAML as well in your .html.haml view file.

```
= raw @layout_1
```

or

```
= @layout_1.html_safe
```

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure this works, but give it a try:

```
- output = Haml::Engine.new(@layout1).render
!= output
```