# Rails add partial to Simpleform custom inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm creating a custom SimpleForm input.  It utilizes a javascript modal popup to select values.

I can basically get it to work if I include the modal partial in the form view, but I would ideally like to have the custom input push the partial to the template.

However, I can't get it to work.  I'm trying this, but it doesn't render the partial correctly.

```
class ProductCategoryImageSelectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
  def input

  html = ''
  html << '<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>'

  File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/views/product_categories/_browse_modal.html.erb", 'r') do |f|
    html << f.read
  end

  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I'm apparently too new of a user to post screenshots, but here are links to the differences in functionality:

When I embed the modal code in the form, I get this, which is the desired functionality:
[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FxEQ.jpg)

When I try to put the modal code in the custom input, I get this instead:
[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4hpk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, it seems I've already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567841/rails-3-haml-how-can-i-output-haml-raw-from-a-variable/8570839#8570839).
Does this work for you?

```
ERB.new(f.read).result(binding)
```

PS: Updated with ERB instead of HAML.

Comment: Sorry to be asking such beginner questions, but I don't use Haml - what would be the html.erb equivalent syntax?

Comment: No such thing as beginner questions. :P I've updated the answer with ERB.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  By the way, I saw in a railscast comment section that you (or at least, someone with the same gravatar image) have put out a new gem for static content.  I'm excited to give it a try!

Comment: Hahah that's me! Hope you like it. Feel free to open an issue or a pull request if you feel like improving it.

Answer (score 6):

You can also render partial from a custom input using the `SimpleForm::FormBuilder` instance which is assigned to an instance variable named `@builder`:

```
class ProductCategoryImageSelectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
  def input
    @builder.template.render(partial: 'product_categories/browse_modal', locals: { foo: 'bar'})
  end
end
```